# Pass Memory Stream Image directly into ImageMagick command in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, imagemagick, memorystream

I am wanting to take an existing Memory Stream image and pass it into ImageMagick execute command directly without saving the file physically to the machine. The code below gives an example what I want to achieve, but I am receiving the following error below.

I do not want to install the entire ImageMagick package and trying to keep the footprint of what is needed very small.

**I would also like the ability to save the output of the ImageMagick command back into the memory stream again. The goal is to pass and use the memory stream entirely without ever saving to the machine*

**Files being used:**

[image: Used Files]

**ImageMagick Version:**

[image: IM7 Properties]

**Code Example:**

```
# Set running location
$Desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
Set-Location "$Desktop\TestImageStream\Core"

# Take existing screnshot and pass as a memory stream
$memoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$imageBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$PWD\TestScreenshot.png")
$memoryStream.Write($imageBytes, 0, $imageBytes.Length)
$memoryStream.Seek(0, 'Begin')

# ImageMagick execute command
.\magick.exe $memoryStream -fill rgb(0,0,0) -opaque rgb(113,113,113) -fuzz 96% TestScreenshotOutput.jpg

# Cleanup
$memoryStream.Dispose()
```

**Error:**

```
magick.exe: UnableToOpenBlob 'System.IO.MemoryStream': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3569

magick.exe: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `MEMORYSTREAM' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/746.
```

Comment: An external executable such as `magick.exe` knows nothing about .NET types; your only option would be to send raw bytes to its stdin, assuming it supports that, which on the PowerShell side is only supported in v7.4+, unless you use lower-level .NET APIs. You need the latter even in v7.4+ if you want to _receive_ raw byte output from an external program in-process. What you're looking for requires a .NET library for in-process use.

Comment: @mklement0 Appreciate the response. I have been having a look at https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET and it seems I might be able to leverage this. At this stage, I am still unclear if this will help me or not and selecting the exact components needed will be a task in itself. I will continue digging but if anyone knows more, please comment :)

Answer (score 1):

I realize you're asking about IM, but [libvips](https://www.libvips.org/) can do what you want (true streaming of images). For example:

```bash
cat k2.jpg | vips flip stdin .png horizontal | cat >x.png
```

That's linux, but it'll work on win too.

The command is using `cat` to send a JPG file as a bytestream down a pipe to the stdin of the `vips` executable. The `vips` exe is running the `flip` operation with the `horizontal` flag, reading from stdin and writing to the PNG format on stdout (enabled by not using a filename before the extension). The final `cat` command is sending the bytestream to a file on disk.

The file will never be fully loaded to memory. Instead, it will be streamed from source to destination in a set of small blocks of pixels. If you have more than one CPU core, the pixels blocks will be evaluated in parallel for a useful speedup. Memory use is low, even for very large images (eg. 500,000 x 500,000 pixels).

I think your difficulty would be in translating those magick command flags. The vips CLI is pretty basic and implementing your fuzz and fill would be painful. You'd be better off using [the .net binding for libvips](https://kleisauke.github.io/net-vips/) and coding the command up there. The .net binding has the same nice properties of streaming, speed (maybe [20x faster than magick.net](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips/tree/master/tests/NetVips.Benchmarks)) and low memory use.